# Deja dup without Google account

Tags: backup

I just wanted to make a backup with Deja Dup, but before I could proceed I first needed let Deja Dup access my Google account.
Is it possible to skip this step? I dont need Deja Dup to access this because I only use an external HDD. From the UI of Deja Dup I cant seem to skip over it.. but maybe there are other ways to skip it

Greetings

Answer (score 1):

this is my own answer after one year... I emailed the google-groups and I got this answer from Michael Terry

``

Hello and thanks for the report! I'm sorry Deja Dup is giving you a hassle.

That is not intentional - it should be possible to use Deja Dup without a Google account for sure. Google Drive is just the default storage location. But if you chose to back up to a USB drive, you shouldn't get prompted for your Google account.

If you go to the Preferences and choose your USB drive in the "Storage Location" part of the preferences, do you still get prompted for your Google account?
``

Hope this helps anyone that somehow missed that option!